# How many ways can you pick out 15 candies total to throw unordered into a bag and take home

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A store sells 8 kinds of candy. How many ways can you pick out 15 candies total to throw unordered into a bag and take home.

here 15 candies..
so we choose 8 from out of 15 is ..=$^{15}C_8$ is i am right

Comment: Hint: Please see Stars and Bars (Wikipedia).

Comment: ok...thank u very much

Comment: i need little explanation..can u please

Comment: i dont understan which one i apply

Answer (score 1):

Call the various types of candy Type 1, Type 2, and so on up to Type 8. Let $x_1$ be the number of Type 1 candies we get, $x_2$ the number of Type 2 candies we get, and so on up to $x_8$.

Then the $x_i$ are non-negative integers, and $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_8=15$.

Conversely, if $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_8$ are non-negative integers with the sum of the $x_i=15$, we can produce a candy selection by choosing $x_1$ of Type 1, $x_2$ of Type 2, and so on up to Type 8.

So the number of different candy selections is the number of solutions of $$x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_8=15\tag{1}$$ in non-negative integers.

By Stars and Bars (please see Wikipedia) Equation (1) has $\binom{15+8-1}{15}$ solutions, or equivalently $\binom{15+8-1}{8-1}$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Something to expand a bit on Andrés answer ( **may be more than you need**, but could maybe be interesting if you are curious. Consider the expression.
$$(x_1+\cdots+x_8)^{15}$$ each time we pick a term in the factor $x_k$, that symbolizes picking candy type $k$. So the possible candy configurations will be each monomial in the expanded sum. For example the term ${x_1}^7{x_2}^8$ would symbolize having picked seven of the first kind and 8 of the second. In other words we are looking for the total number of such terms. Now the coefficients of each monomial will be the number of possible orders we can pick them. So this approach gives a bit of more information than we need (right now).

A minimal example would be $(x_1+x_2)^2 = {x_1}^2 + 2x_1x_2 + {x_2}^2$ where the coefficient 2 means that we can first pick candy 1 and then 2 or first candy 2 and then candy 1 ( two configurations ).

Answer (score 0):

The number $\binom{15}{8}$ represents the number of ways of making an unordered selection of eight objects from a set of $15$ distinct objects.

In this problem, we are instead selecting $15$ pieces of candy from eight different types of candy.  What matters is how many candies of each type we choose.  If $x_k$ represents the number of candies of type $k$, $1 \leq k \leq 8$, then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 15$$
Assuming there are at least $15$ candies of each type available, we need to determine the number of solutions of this equation in the non-negative integers.  A particular corresponds to the placement of seven addition signs in a row of $15$ ones.  For instance,
$$1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 + + 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 2$, $x_3 = 3$, $x_4 = 0$, $x_5 = 2$, $x_6 = 3$, $x_7 = 1$, and $x_8 = 3$. Thus, the number of solutions of the equation is the number of ways of inserting seven addition signs into a row of $15$ ones, which is 
$$\binom{15 + 7}{7} = \binom{22}{7}$$
since we must choose which seven of the twenty-two symbols ($15$ ones and $7$ addition signs) will be addition signs.